# Firebase Remote Config feature for web app (after Firebase expansion)

Tags: web-applications, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am building a web application with Firebase and I saw they released their expansion with all great new features. However, the Remote Config section is now only available for Android and IOS apps. Is there a way to apply the remote config also on web app as well?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Since September 2019 it is possible to use Remote Config from your web applications. Have a look at [Get started with Firebase Remote Config on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-web) to get started.

Comment: well, that stops me from using FRC since it's not a `true` cross platform solution. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Why don't you just use the realtime database for configurations? Just add a configuration node and add your parameters... Your web app can instantly apply changes when using an event listener.

Comment: @MarcelDieterle on the app side that would indeed be similar. But you'd miss the UI for configuring the values, including targeting based on audience.

Comment: Any news on this new feature?

Comment: if you like to have similar feature like firebase remote config in your webapp, try GTM (Google Tag Manager).

Comment: This is important to our organization so that we can use remote config in all of our environments.

Comment: I'd like that too. Seems to be great for A/B testing

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any update or notice? It would be really useful, we'll stick to realtime database until it's available. Thanks!

Comment: The Remote Config REST API is now available. You can see the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest) @OhadPerry

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes The REST API is (currently) only for editing the Remote Config templates. It is not for use in regular web clients (similar to the iOS and Android SDKs), which is what OP seems to be asking for.

Comment: I understand Frank, and thanks for the clarification. I was just telling Ohad the news, since he mentioned he would love to see this API :)

Comment: @Frank: Is that still the case? [Use the Remote Config REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest) starts with "This document describes how you can use the Remote Config REST API to **read and modify** the set of JSON-formatted parameters and conditions known as the Remote Config template."

Comment: You can read the template, but that doesn't yet resolve the variables as the serve does when accessed a client. In other words: the REST API is for modifying the variable, replacing the console. It is not for replacing the Android/iOS SDK, or building your own SDK on platforms where one isn't available.

Comment: Is there any update about this topic? or any Beta for web?
When I use Flutter and will use it also for Web soon, does Firebase add features that are iOS and Android only to Web to support it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how about A/B testing with remote config, I think it's still not enabled for web?

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in remote config on the web I suggest the following tips:
I did this on my web app and it is working perfectly.

in the firebase database create a config node for example:

```
sampleFirebaseDB-c2555
{
    config : 
    {
    'lang':'EN',
     'color':'blue',    ...
    }
}
```

read that from javascript using regular firebase database read

```
firebase.database.ref('/config/').once('value').then(function(snap){

});
```

and store that in an object or locally.
and you can access the object proprietes by dot notation in your application

and to change the config you can make an admin page to change those database objects or to change them in firebase directly

I hope that helps :D

Comment: Hi jwdsoft. Remote configs are not merely preferences only. This feature also takes care of conditional values for various properties on the basis of location, percentile etc.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase released a Remote Config REST API on 3/7/2018.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Please note that this REST API is primarily designed for developers to edit or configure their Remote Config values from a custom tool or service. This should *not* be used by a consumer-facing web client.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is google optimize if you are only doing web stuff. If you need to target all 3 platforms with one tool though not sure if it would be useful for that.

https://www.google.com/analytics/optimize/